# How to Lower Heap Size of WebSphere Server

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I tried to change the Heap Size of my local WebSphere Server instance to 2G using the "Run Administrative Console" function in RAD but apparently, that was too big of a number. Now, I can't start the server anymore and I get this error:

```
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc23(2): Failed to instantiate heap.  2G requested
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I can't just change it back to a lower number because I can't seem to use the "Run Admin Console" function without starting the server first so I was wondering if anyone knew where the config file is kept for this? How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Work with the server.xml under the config/cells/**cellName**/nodes/**nodename**/servers/**servername**/ directory.

cellName and nodename would likley be based on your host name. I have kept them as cellName (and nodename) here in the structure above.

The servername would be the default server1

Look towards the bottom of the file

It would have something like this: (Change the initialHeapSize and maximumHeapSize)

Save the file and start your server and you should be able wot work with the server.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: I have 20Gb of ram on server. But I am unable to give 2gb. Why?

Comment: The heapsize of a 32 bit JVM is limited to a lower value. If you want to have a JVM with higher heap size look at 64 bit machines and the limits are pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

**I have the same issue in IBM Engineering lifecycle installation:-**

**Problem:-**
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc26(2): Failed to instantiate heap;
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

**Solution:-**
I just did it and solve my issue.
If you don't have 16GB ram then please don't change the jazz server startup file.
If you have 8GB ram then Only do not increase memory size in the server.:
`**set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx4G**    **set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms4G**    **set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmn1G**`